# angular - Attempting to post authorization header but getting 404 whereas same post works in Postman

Tags: angular

I am relatively new to Angular, but not to development.

I understand how the http post is supposed to work. My own function is based on the Hero Service tutorial post example.

The problem is that this post works perfectly fine in Postman. I receive an authorization token as expected. However, when I run the angular app and see my console, I receive a 404 not found which is exactly what I receive if I do GET to the same URL in Postman.

```
{
    "statusCode": 404,
    "error": "Not Found"
}
```

Below is my service and some screenshots that may be helpful.

Any ideas?

Need additional information I can provide?

Thanks in advance.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class TheService {
  private baseUrl = 'https://someserver.com';  
  private authUrl = this.baseUrl + '/auth';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getAuth(apiKey: string): Promise<string> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + apiKey);

    console.log('headers: ' + headers.get('Authorization'));

    return this.http
      .post(this.authUrl, '', {headers: headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log('response:' + response.toString());
        return response.toString();
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
      console.error('An error occurred', error); 
      return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }

}
```

[image: Postman POST request returning valid token]

[image: Chrome console 404 error]

Comment: i think is the cors. in browser console. it resolves the 404 with GET  or OPTIONS

Comment: @JesusCarrasco Thanks for the info. Can you expand on that?

Comment: when using custom headers in angular browser always resolves first with an OPTIONS method so in you api you need to allow this method.

Comment: Where is `apiKey` defined?  You are getting `"Collection 'undefined' not found"`, which seems to indicate that the server is having a hard time retrieving the data, likely because your `apiKey` is missing?

Comment: @JesusCarrasco Unfortunately, I don't have access to the server where the api is located.

Comment: @Claies In the service.ts code, I am printing out the apiKey that is being passed in from a component and I do see the Authorization header. `console.log('headers: ' + headers.get('Authorization'));`

Comment: that would be a problem cause always the browser will send de OPTIONS before the  GET or other METHOD  to the api.

Comment: if you can contact the provider of the api should comment the OPTIONS issue if he can support to it..  it suppose that if an RESTFULL api, it might be  OPTIONS succesfully allowed.